# Программирование, JAVA, Android Studio, GET-запрос, JSON

Tags: android, json, android-studio, get

Подскажите пожалуйста как запросить информацию с сервера (там лежит файл number.json) и нажимая на кнопку в приложении получить ее в текстовом окне. Разработка в Android Studio. Желательно Retrofit, ну или что-то похожее, лишь бы ответ приходил в формате JSON

Comment: https://startandroid.ru/ru/blog/506-retrofit.html

Comment: Уточните что именно не получается, сделать запрос с ретрофита или отобразить информацию, если проблемы с кодом - предоставьте

Comment: не могли бы вы пожалуйста помочь мне, я даже не представляю каким должен быть код...

Comment: startandroid.ru/ru/blog/506-retrofit.html не получается, ну или я что-то не так делаю, не могу разобраться с этой задачей